# How do I get a new TextView text to appear every time a button is clicked

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, textview, android

I am new to this sorry. I am trying to create an Android Studio app that will have a different text appear for a question and answer TextView box field when a button is clicked. I was able to figure out how to get the text to change once, but how do I get it to cycle repeatedly every time the button is clicked?

Example Question and Answer I Want To Include for each time the button is clicked:

What is your Name?
My Name is Alyssa!

What is your age?
I am 28 years old.

What did you eat today?
I ate Spaghetti and Meatballs.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.kt

```
package example.alyssa.com.askalyssa

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlin.random.Random


class MainActivity : Activity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

}

fun buttonClick(v: View) {
    val tv = findViewById(R.id.welcome) as TextView
    tv.text = "Hi! I'm Alyssa"
    val question = findViewById(R.id.questionfield) as TextView
    question.text = "What is your name?"
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
        android:text="Avatar Response Field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/welcome" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" 
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
/>
<TextView
        android:text="Question Pop Up Field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:id="@+id/questionfield" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"/>
<Button
        android:text="Click to Ask Alyssa a Question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" 
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"/>
<ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="301dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/welcome" 
android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" 
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/questionfield"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't understand your question completely but what i found is you are not listening the click of a button. So either implements the setonclickListner with MainActivity or you can directly use btn.setOnClickListner and perform the action on the textview accordingly.
If you still face any issue please comment here with proper query . i will surely help you.